# Python 3.7 Issue with append function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm learning Python and decided to adapte code from an example to scrape Craigslist data to look at prices of cars. https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-craigslist-a-complete-tutorial-c41cea4f4981

I've created a Jupyter notebook and modified the code for my use. I recreated the same error when running the code in Spyder Python 3.7.

I'm running into an issue at line 116. 
File "C:/Users/UserM/Documents/GitHub/learning/Spyder Python Craigslist Scrape Untitled0.py", line 116
post_prices.append(post_price). I receive a "SynaxError: invalid syntax".

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Oct  2 12:26:06 2019

"""

#import get to call a get request on the site
from requests import get

#get the first page of the Chicago car prices
response = get('https://chicago.craigslist.org/search/cto?bundleDuplicates=1') #eliminate duplicates and show owner only sales
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

#get the macro-container for the housing posts
posts = html_soup.find_all('li', class_= 'result-row')
print(type(posts)) #to double check that I got a ResultSet
print(len(posts)) #to double check I got 120 (elements/page

#grab the first post
post_one = posts[0]

#grab the price of the first post
post_one_price = post_one.a.text
post_one_price.strip()

#grab the time of the post in datetime format to save on cleaning efforts
post_one_time = post_one.find('time', class_= 'result-date')
post_one_datetime = post_one_time['datetime']

#title is a and that class, link is grabbing the href attribute of that variable
post_one_title = post_one.find('a', class_='result-title hdrlnk')
post_one_link = post_one_title['href']

#easy to grab the post title by taking the text element of the title variable
post_one_title_text = post_one_title.text

#the neighborhood is grabbed by finding the span class 'result-hood' and pulling the text element from that
post_one_hood = posts[0].find('span', class_='result-hood').text

#the price is grabbed by finding the span class 'result-price' and pulling the text element from that
post_one_hood = posts[0].find('span', class_='result-price').text

#build out the loop
from time import sleep
import re
from random import randint #avoid throttling by not sending too many requests one after the other
from warnings import warn
from time import time
from IPython.core.display import clear_output
import numpy as np

#find the total number of posts to find the limit of the pagination
results_num = html_soup.find('div', class_= 'search-legend')
results_total = int(results_num.find('span', class_='totalcount').text) #pulled the total count of posts as the upper bound of the pages array

#each page has 119 posts so each new page is defined as follows: s=120, s=240, s=360, and so on. So we need to step in size 120 in the np.arange function
pages = np.arange(0, results_total+1, 120)

iterations = 0

post_timing = []
post_hoods = []
post_title_texts = []
post_links = []
post_prices = []

for page in pages:

    #get request
    response = get("https://chicago.craigslist.org/search/cto?bundleDuplicates=1" 
                   + "s=" #the parameter for defining the page number 
                   + str(page) #the page number in the pages array from earlier
                   + "&hasPic=1"
                   + "&availabilityMode=0")

    sleep(randint(1,5))

    #throw warning for status codes that are not 200
    if response.status_code != 200:
        warn('Request: {}; Status code: {}'.format(requests, response.status_code))

    #define the html text
    page_html = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    #define the posts
    posts = html_soup.find_all('li', class_= 'result-row')

    #extract data item-wise
    for post in posts:

        if post.find('span', class_ = 'result-hood') is not None:

            #posting date
            #grab the datetime element 0 for date and 1 for time
            post_datetime = post.find('time', class_= 'result-date')['datetime']
            post_timing.append(post_datetime)

            #neighborhoods
            post_hood = post.find('span', class_= 'result-hood').text
            post_hoods.append(post_hood)

            #title text
            post_title = post.find('a', class_='result-title hdrlnk')
            post_title_text = post_title.text
            post_title_texts.append(post_title_text)

            #post link
            post_link = post_title['href']
            post_links.append(post_link)

              #removes the \n whitespace from each side, removes the currency symbol, and turns it into an int
            #test removed: post_price = int(post.a.text.strip().replace("$", "")) 
            post_price = int(float((post.a.text.strip().replace("$", "")))  #does this work??
            post_prices.append(post_price)



    iterations += 1
    print("Page " + str(iterations) + " scraped successfully!")

print("\n")

print("Scrape complete!")

import pandas as pd

eb_apts = pd.DataFrame({'posted': post_timing,
                       'neighborhood': post_hoods,
                       'post title': post_title_texts,
                       'URL': post_links,
                       'price': post_prices})
print(eb_apts.info())
eb_apts.head(10)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow....  If this has solved your question, please accept the answer as shown here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow. Usually when you see syntax errors in already working code, it means that you've either messed up indentation, forgot to terminate a string somewhere, or missed a closing bracket.

You can tell this when a line of what looks to be ok code is throwing you a syntax error. This is because the line before isn't ended properly and the interpreter is giving you hints around where to look.

In this case, you're short a paranthesis in the line before.

`post_price = int(float((post.a.text.strip().replace("$", "")))`

should be

`post_price = int(float((post.a.text.strip().replace("$", ""))))`

or delete the extra paranthesis after `float`

`post_price = int(float(post.a.text.strip().replace("$", "")))`

Comment: Thanks, great comment. I voted it up. Since I'm new, I can't give you credit for your response!